# HIP error during rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, error, gpu

This is the error message that blender 3.4.0 gives when trying to render on an RX6700 XT video card. The video card is new, there are no problems in other applications and games. The latest drivers are installed. What can this problem be related to and can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: There are no  Blender developers here so you should report it as a bug via Blender's Help > Report a bug menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhh don't know how the problem triggered. But AMD-HIP don't support 8K+ resolution(idk maybe 16K+) texture (e.g., HDRi for environment). Maybe you can use simplify in render settings and toggle Texture Limit to 8192.
This just my guessing. If the problem still happens, contact to developers

Comment: You were right. The problem disappeared when I chose a different HDRI for this project. I was not aware of such restrictions. Thanks.